# Pandas Renaming columns

Tags: pandas, rename

These are the columns of my DataFrame:

```
    col_list= df1.columns
    Out:

    Index([              nan,               nan,        'Estimate',
   'Margin of Error',         'Percent', 'Margin of Error',
          'Estimate', 'Margin of Error',         'Percent',
   'Margin of Error',        'Estimate', 'Margin of Error',
           'Percent', 'Margin of Error',        'Estimate',
   'Margin of Error',         'Percent', 'Margin of Error',
          'Estimate', 'Margin of Error',         'Percent',
   'Margin of Error',        'Estimate', 'Margin of Error',
           'Percent', 'Margin of Error',        'Estimate',
   'Margin of Error',         'Percent', 'Margin of Error',
          'Estimate', 'Margin of Error',         'Percent',
   'Margin of Error',        'Estimate', 'Margin of Error',
           'Percent', 'Margin of Error',        'Estimate',
   'Margin of Error',         'Percent', 'Margin of Error'],
  dtype='object', name=3)
```

I am trying to rename the first two columns names:

```
    df2= df1.rename(columns={df1.columns[0]:'State', df1.columns[1]:'coverage'})
```

But both the columns get renamed to 'coverage'

However when I try to look individuals column names like:

```
   col[0]
   Out: nan
   col[1]
   Out:nan
   col[3]
   Out: 'Estimate'
```

It resolves to the correct positions. 
Even when I try to rename only the first columns as,

```
    df2= df1.rename(columns={df1.columns[0]:'State'})
```

The first column names changes to 'State':

```
    Index(['State', 'State', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent',
   'Margin of Error'],
  dtype='object', name=3)
```

Not sure what's happening here.

Comment: The first two columns, have nan as column (same value), The solution i would give to you is to reassign all the columns by doing this df.columns = ['State', 'coverage'] + df.columns[2:]

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
df2= df1.rename(columns={df1.columns[0]:'State', df1.columns[1]:'coverage'})
```

`df1.columns[0]` and `df1.columns[1]` is grabbing the value of the name of the 0th\1st column, which is `nan` for both. So that is equivalent to:

```
df2= df1.rename(columns={'nan':'State', 'nan':'coverage'})
```

Since the 'nan' key is appearing twice, the second assignment is taking precedence.

The workaround is to rename all the columns at once:

```
col_list= df1.columns.to_list()
col_list[0] = 'State'
col_list[1] = 'coverage'
df1.columns = col_list
```

or in a one-liner (as @IWHKYB's suggestion):

```
df1.columns = ['State', 'coverage'] + df1.columns[2:].to_list()
```

Comment: df1.columns = ['State', 'coverage'] + df1.columns[2:]
Gave me this error:

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 42 elements, new values have 40 elements. 

Also, I'd tried col_list[0]= 'State', earlier. It resulted in:
 
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations

So, I just took the same logic and assigned the columns to a list: 

         df1.columns= ['State', 'Coverage', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent', 'Margin of Error', 'Estimate', 'Margin of Error', 'Percent', 'Margin of Error'...]

Comment: Ahh `Index` does not exactly behave like a list. Edited to add `to_list()` calls.